# Strategy for deploying CFML application with subversion?

Tags: svn, coldfusion, jenkins

Our team uses SVN to keep track of our day-to-day development.  However, when it comes to deploying to QA and Live, we are not sure what to do.

Heard of Jenkins but not sure if we want to deal with the overhead of learning that, unless it would really assist us on what we want.

How to use Branch or Tag to:

- ease of reverting to last working state
- keep track of what's being deployed, when and what exactly being deployed
- how to push updates to QA, then to Live

Right now, every developer just commit everything to Head.  So Head, although stable, is not guaranteed to be stable.

Use symbolic link? IIS virtual folder? to point to a version instead of overwriting for live?  Or should Live be an export from SVN?

Any suggestion? Thanks!

I'm a little scared of Branch / Merging in SVN 'cause if SVN says something's wrong, we often stuck there.

There are multiple way of merging, and if the developer choose the incorrect way, then the svn will be screwed, and it does seem easy to undo things in SVN.

We don't want to use Git as of now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Jenkins is an automated build server, and since ColdFusion applications are not compiled, it will not help you any more than svn by itself.  I'm sure there are some compelling features that are available for CF apps, but like you said, the learning curve might not be worth the effort.

We have the same dev/QA/Prod tiers as you do, and svn suits our needs just fine.  The process goes something like this:

1. Developers check out the HEAD branch using Subclipse or TortoiseSVN
2. Developers check in features to HEAD.
3. A system admin checks out HEAD to the QA server when features need testing
4. If HEAD passes QA, then a branch is created to go to production.  This branch is just a copy of HEAD that has been vetted by QA.  We name the branch folder prod_2_7_2012 or something similar.
5. A sysadmin uses svn to check out the project to the production server. Sometimes a full export & overwrite is done if svn is not available.
6. Developers check out the prod branch using subclipse/tortoise. They now have 2 copies of the app in their dev environment.
7. QA checks out the prod branch.
8. Devs may ONLY commit emergency bug fixes to the prod branch, which will be vetted by QA.
9. If the bugfix is approved, prod is updated with svn update or export.
10. The bugfix is also applied to HEAD and committed to HEAD.  This duplicates work, but alleviates the headache of merging.
11. When new features in HEAD are ready for production, the process repeats and the old prod branch is archived.

No merging.

Comment: Also, when doing the 'dual bugfix' approach, you can add an extra layer of validation by doing a diff between HEAD and your existing prod branch before creating a new prod branch from HEAD. This usually catches anything that a dev might have forgotten.

Comment: I like this, but I need some time to evaluate if this approach would work for our team.  No merging is a big plus, takes quite a bit of complexity and eliminate risk of failed / incorrect merge

Comment: This works well with a small to medium size dev team (3-8 devs) that are all able to communicate well with each other and catch each others mistakes. It's important to make sure that everyone is working on the same dev/prod pair when fixing bugs, and it's easy for someone to get lost on a huge team.

Answer (score 1):

Best thing to do is research all the recommended best practices for Branching and Merging.
This is the MSDN article regarding strategy but there are far more opinions:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee782536.aspx

Best thing to do? Figure out what best fits your team and use that. Once you have figured out what you want to do, then figure out your build and deploy strategy.

The easiest pattern to follow is use Main to do development, branch on each release from Main. That way your new development and your bug fixes are seperated. Do Reverse integration from Release to pick up your bugs when needed.

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.planning.html oh, just realized it is not what I want.

Comment: No problem! Make sure to keep it simple, you can get really crazy with your strategy but it ends up just causing headaches.

Answer (score 1):

One more small thing that hasn't been noted is to commit and update often.  As soon as a dev gets all the unit tests to pass when working on a feature (assuming that there is unit tests) or bug fix they should commit. They should update even more frequently in my opinion.

Nothing kills productivity like resolving a bunch of conflicts because of a stale repository.

Comment: Thanks, would you mind sharing your current deployment strategy?  Something high level like eterps's answer would be great.  Thank you.

Comment: To be honest we don't have a lot of set rules since our team is small(ish), we usually have 2-5 developers working on a project at a time.  When we start a new project all developers are developing in trunk on a single are of responsibility.  As soon as we go beta we tag the trunk 0.1 and push code to our staging server for our client.  From there, all modifications are done in a feature branch, when they get merged back into trunk a new version is tagged and pushed.

Answer (score 1):

My team uses the approach that /trunk should be able to be sent to production at any time. We do all development (both feature development and bug fixes) in separate branches and create tags from trunk when we release a new version. These tags never change once they are created.

Branches are merged back into trunk only after testing has been completed against the feature and all unit tests for the entire project pass. During development, we merge from /trunk to the branch we are working in usually daily to keep our development branches caught up with /trunk.

I've seen a couple of different approaches to getting code from a tag to the production server. The route we're taking at present is to make the production server simply a working copy (checked out to a specific tag) and configure Apache to not serve up the files in the .svn folders. That way when a new version comes out, it's as simple as doing an svn switch command to the new tag and reinit'ing my app. Furthermore, it keeps everything neatly separated in SVN so you can easily roll-back to previous tags if something slips past your QA process.

Don't be afraid of merging. If you keep up with it and don't let it languish for weeks on end between merges it's no big deal.

Comment: Thanks.  It seems like there are many ways to merge and sometimes it can get confusing which one to use.  See: http://subclipse.tigris.org/images/merge/page1.png

Comment: Yes, I understand. Since SVN 1.6, which included some very helpful merge tracking features, we've not had any issues. In that graphic, the first option "merge a range of revision" is what we use to "catch up" a branch with the latest changes from trunk. The second option is what we use once a branch is ready to be merged back into trunk. I don't think I've ever had occasion to use any of the other options.